# Strange multiple return values in Python

Tags: python

Just 5 days into Python, learning through Code Academy. I have no knowledge of any other language (very little knowledge of Ruby!).

What am I doing wrong with this code?

---

> Q: Write a function, `by_three`, that calls a second function, `cube`,
>   if a number is evenly divisible by 3 and `"False"` otherwise. You should
>   then return the result you get from `cube`. As for `cube`, that function
>   should return the cube of the number passed from `by_three`. (Cubing a
>   number is the same as raising it to the third power).
>
> So, for example, `by_three` should take 9, determine it's evenly
>   divisible by 3, and pass it to cube, who returns 729 (the result of
>   9**3). If `by_three` gets 4, however, it should return `False` and leave
>   it at that.
>
> Lastly, call `by_three` on 11, 12, and 13 on three separate lines.

ANS:

```
def by_three(n):
    orig_num = n
    if (isinstance(orig_num, int) and orig_num%3 == 0 ):
        cube(orig_num)
    else:
        print "False"

def cube(orig_num):
    cube = orig_num**3
    print cube
    return

by_three(11)
by_three(12)
by_three(13)
```

When I run the above code, here is what I get.  Why do these values appear in this way?

```
False
1728
False
==> None
False
False
1728
Oops, try again.
```

Comment: You should not use the same name for a function and for an internal variable.

Comment: @madth3 thanks. Did changes accordingly and still the same result!

def by_three(n):

 if (isinstance(n, int) and n%3 == 0 ):
  cube(n)
 else:
  print "False"
 
def cube(m):
 cube = m**3
 print cube
 return

by_three(11)
by_three(12)
by_three(13)

Comment: It looks like you may have some other code at work here (for instance, Python doesn't say 'Oops, try again' :) ). Although what you have doesn't quite match the requirements from a purely `return` perspective, it will return the correct result when run on its own.

Comment: yes. it was an "exercise" in codeAcademy. I did put in effort and since I couldn't understand the error, I'm asking you guys for help.

Comment: @RocketDonkey thanks. I'm using the codeacademy.com interpreter. Assume  'Oops, try again' is their doing. Still the question remains on why it is running twice. The first time, expected result appears and then it runs again, giving the wrong result.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense then :) Check out @RohitJain's solution below - the way that he structures the returns is in-line with what you want, and doing so may alleviate your problems. Good luck!

Comment: "y is it running twice" ? what does it mean? did you should all code? why it has 8 line output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say why you're seeing odd results. When I copy your code into the interpreter, I see:

```
>>> def by_three(n):
...     orig_num = n
...     if (isinstance(orig_num, int) and orig_num%3 == 0 ):
...         cube(orig_num)
...     else:
...         print "False"
... 
>>> def cube(orig_num):
...     cube = orig_num**3
...     print cube
...     return
... 
>>> by_three(11)
False
>>> by_three(12)
1728
>>> by_three(13)
False
```

I think this problem is a lot simpler than you're making it, though. It's hard to tell because the question is rather poorly written, but this would be my answer:

```
def by_three(n): return False if n % 3 else cube(n)

def cube(n): return n**3

by_three(11)
by_three(12)
by_three(13)
```

And this is what it looks like in the interpreter:

```
>>> def by_three(n): return False if n % 3 else cube(n)
... 
>>> def cube(n): return n**3
... 
>>> by_three(11)
False
>>> by_three(12)
1728
>>> by_three(13)
False
```

Comment: superb! thanks, man. I'm sorry about the "poorly written" question. That is how it was put in the "exercise". but, thanks! :)

Comment: Please do not use isinstance() - catch TypeError instead.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change the `cube` function to actually return the `cube`. And you can even simplify your `cube` method, by just returning the `cube` without storing the temporary result: -

```
def cube(orig_num):
    return orig_num**3   # Just return the cube
```

Then in your `by_three` function, rather than printing "False", you should return it. Also, return the `value` returned by `cube` function: -

```
def by_three(n):
    if (isinstance(n, int) and n % 3 == 0):
        return cube(n)  # Added return here
    else:
        return False  #Changed print to return.
```

You can also simplify this method to just a `single` line return statement. You should use `try-except` block instead of checking instance with `isinstance`, if you are passing a value in your `function`: -

```
def by_three(n):
    try:
        return cube(n) if n % 3 == 0 else False
    except TypeError, e:
        return False
```

And then, when you invoke the method, print the result obtained: -

```
print by_three(11)
print by_three(12)
print by_three(13)
```

Comment: Instead of isinstance() you should rather use try-except statements catching TypeError. In Python checking for type of passed value in similar cases is considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

In your `cube` method, you're not actually *returning* anything.  Unlike Ruby, which returns the last statement in the block, you have to explicitly state what you're returning.  There's also no need to create defensive copies of the value.  Furthermore, you can't reuse the name `cube`, or that will clobber your method definition.

```
def cube(orig_num):
    return orig_num ** 3
```

Next, you would have to return the values in your caller method.  I'll leave that as an exercise for you - shouldn't be too tricky to figure out from here.

Third, you (sort of) don't need to worry if the number is an int or a float.  While there is imprecision with floating point numbers, the values shouldn't be perfectly divisible by 3.